# Understanding Testbench Waveform for UART module

Tags: verilog, uart, testbench

I have taken the following code for testing a UART module from https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html

Can anyone explain what is happening in the `\\ Main Testing` block? On **running the testbench file, the waveform shows `ab` for `r_tx_byte` and `3f` for `w_rx_byte`? How do I understand this?** Someone please explain.

I have also attached the waveform figure. Please note that the module file also has been taken from the same website.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// File Downloaded from http://www.nandland.com
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// This testbench will exercise both the UART Tx and Rx.
// It sends out byte 0xAB over the transmitter
// It then exercises the receive by receiving byte 0x3F
`timescale 1ns/10ps

`include "uart_tx.v"
`include "uart_rx.v"

module uart_tb ();

  // Testbench uses a 10 MHz clock
  // Want to interface to 115200 baud UART
  // 10000000 / 115200 = 87 Clocks Per Bit.
  parameter c_CLOCK_PERIOD_NS = 100;
  parameter c_CLKS_PER_BIT    = 87;
  parameter c_BIT_PERIOD      = 8600;

  reg r_Clock = 0;
  reg r_Tx_DV = 0;
  wire w_Tx_Done;
  reg [7:0] r_Tx_Byte = 0;
  reg r_Rx_Serial = 1;
  wire [7:0] w_Rx_Byte;


  // Takes in input byte and serializes it 
  task UART_WRITE_BYTE;
    input [7:0] i_Data;
    integer     ii;
    begin

      // Send Start Bit
      r_Rx_Serial <= 1'b0;
      #(c_BIT_PERIOD);
      #1000;


      // Send Data Byte
      for (ii=0; ii<8; ii=ii+1)
        begin
          r_Rx_Serial <= i_Data[ii];
          #(c_BIT_PERIOD);
        end

      // Send Stop Bit
      r_Rx_Serial <= 1'b1;
      #(c_BIT_PERIOD);
     end
  endtask // UART_WRITE_BYTE


  uart_rx #(.CLKS_PER_BIT(c_CLKS_PER_BIT)) UART_RX_INST
    (.i_Clock(r_Clock),
     .i_Rx_Serial(r_Rx_Serial),
     .o_Rx_DV(),
     .o_Rx_Byte(w_Rx_Byte)
     );

  uart_tx #(.CLKS_PER_BIT(c_CLKS_PER_BIT)) UART_TX_INST
    (.i_Clock(r_Clock),
     .i_Tx_DV(r_Tx_DV),
     .i_Tx_Byte(r_Tx_Byte),
     .o_Tx_Active(),
     .o_Tx_Serial(),
     .o_Tx_Done(w_Tx_Done)
     );


  always
    #(c_CLOCK_PERIOD_NS/2) r_Clock <= !r_Clock;


  // Main Testing:
  initial
    begin

      // Tell UART to send a command (exercise Tx)
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      r_Tx_DV <= 1'b1;
      r_Tx_Byte <= 8'hAB;
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      r_Tx_DV <= 1'b0;
      @(posedge w_Tx_Done);

      // Send a command to the UART (exercise Rx)
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      UART_WRITE_BYTE(8'h3F);
      @(posedge r_Clock);

      // Check that the correct command was received
      if (w_Rx_Byte == 8'h3F)
        $display("Test Passed - Correct Byte Received");
      else
        $display("Test Failed - Incorrect Byte Received");

    end

endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This simulation follows the fundamental of the [UVM](http://www.accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.2.pdf).

[image: overview of the UVM]

Note, that this is not an UVM simulation, just we can substitute the parts into an UVM style simulation.

The DUTs are the `uart_rx` and `uart_tx`.

The testbench is the `uart_tb`. This implements the interfaces to the board.

The `task UART_WRITE_BYTE` is the driver. This task transform the high level transaction to the low level interfaces.

The `Main Testing` block controls the testing. This block starts the stimulus and check the response (scoreboard)